# Kronecker delta identity for orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a textbook and I came upon the following identity:

$\delta_{ij} = n_i n_j + m_i m_j + p_i p_j$

where **m**,**n** and **p** are orthonormal vectors. Can someone help me prove this?  I've tried using this fact that these are unit vectors that are orthogonal to each other, but I never get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, if we denote by $A$ the matrix with columns the vectors $m,n,p$, $A$ is clearly an orthogonal matrix, i.e., such that identity $I=A^TA$ holds. This identity can be written under the form

$$I=m^Tm+n^Tn+p^Tp.$$

As $I$ has generic entry $\delta_{ij}$ and for example matrix $m^Tm$ has generic entry  $m_im_j$, we find back your formula.